# Keep the bouncing css element rotated in animate css

Tags: html, css, animate.css

I'm using animate.css to bounce an element. But while its bouncing, I want it to remain rotated. Here's what I've done:

```
.rotateBounce {
     background:#fefabc;
     -moz-transform: rotate(7deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(7deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg);
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

HTML is as follows

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3" >
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 rotateBounce animated bounce" style="float:left; margin-top:22.5%;margin-left:2.5%;background:#B6EDA7" >
        <p>Road Trips</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Even though the element is bouncing, the rotate effect seems to be overridden. I tried adding inline CSS to the elements but that didn't seem to work either. How can I achieve this effect?

edit: here's the animate and bounce css

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
        transform: translateY(-30px);
    }

    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
        transform: translateY(-15px);
    };
}

@keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
        transform: translateY(-30px);
    }

    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
        transform: translateY(-15px);
    };
}

.bounce {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
    animation-name: bounce;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide `.animated` and `.bounce` CSS code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes within animate.css are somehow conflicting your custom rules so an approach you can take would to simply wrap your current element with a parent and apply `.rotateBounce` such as

```
<div class="rotateBounce">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 rotateBounce animated bounce" style="float:left; margin-top:22.5%;margin-left:2.5%;background:#B6EDA7" >
        <p>Road Trips</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/q4cd0s7m/)